# Keeping a sub site running after switching the main site off

Tags: ee2, multi-site-manager

I have 2 websites, I'll call them website mainsite.com & website subsite.com to help illustrate what I'm trying to do.

subsite.com is a subsite of mainsite.com (durr), and mainsite.com is currently being rebuilt in a completely separate CMS but subsite.com needs to stay as it is.

Currently, the only way to edit subsite.com is through mainsite.com/system.

What I'm trying to work out, is when the new mainsite.com site goes live, what can I do about keeping subsite.com running and while keeping access to editing it etc.

The site is running Expression Engine 2.5.2 (an old legacy site I was handed over).

Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at merging your bootstrap `index.php` file and working on a solution there. Something simple like this:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "mainsite.com") {

    /* Paste the contents of your new CMS index.php file here */

}

if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "subsite.com") {

    /* Paste the contents of your old EE index.php file here */

}
```

It also may not be necessary... if your EE MSM `subsite.com` is in it's own child folder, than requests for `subsite.com` are getting routed to the `index.php` file in that sub-folder via the `.htaccess` file. You would just need to leave your `system` folder in place. Then in your webroot, use the `index.php` file for your new CMS. No reason everything can't run side by side.

Comment: Sorry for the flow response I've been away until today.

Thanks for your reply, I think the issue I'll have with this answer is the new site is completely different and will be on a separate server, while the subsite is currently staying as is.

I guess the perfect solution would be swapping the current subsite.com to become the main site, and just changing the DNS on mainsite.com.

Can you see that being a possibility?

Thanks, Harry.